# Wordpress Force Redirect to https some page not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

I want my website always show "https://www.example.com" if user click another URL format must be direct to full URL with www and https

I try to force my WordPress website always using https in .htaccess file, I found all it working to redirect to https, except some URL like this "http://example.com/category"

But if I enter "/" at the end URL like this "http://example.com/category/" redirect rule is working !!

my .htaccess code is below and my website run at cloudways

```
# BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>

   # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the top of your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/forcing-http-to-https-and-non-www-to-www/

Comment: thank you for your comment ,try your code i got error to many redirect connection

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would strongly suggest to not use redirects in the .htaccess file, but to simply Define the URL address of the Wordpress which you can set from the back-end Settings where you set the URL address and also include it in the 'wp-config.php' :

> Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where “example.com” is the correct location of your site.
>
> define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com' );
>
> define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.com' );

As mentioned in the following article:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

By performing it like that you will escape a redirecting process and assist with a 'optimization' of the site. Also google and other search engines will cache the default address with 'HTTPS' making less to none redirects which is = to less loading time on the site.